# How to make a react component that can be controled from outside?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I'm trying to make a Dialog component using React and Material-UI.

For now, I have the traditional behavior of the Material-UI dialog with a button inside the class that can open the dialog. But the behavior that i want for this component is the same that the Material-UI dialog have.

So I want to change his state and re-render the component calling it like this:

```
var open = false;
<AuthDialog open={open} />
```

And using an outside button that change the open variable to true.

This is my Code:

```
class AuthDialog extends React.Component {
    constructor(props, context){
        super(props, context);

        this.state = {
           open: false,
        };
    };

    handleRequestOpen = () => {
        this.setState({
            open: true,
        });
    };

    handleRequestClose = () => {
        this.setState({
            open: false,
        });
    };

    render() {
        return (
        <div>
            <RaisedButton children="login" onTouchTap={ this.handleRequestOpen } />
            <Dialog open={this.state.open} onRequestClose={this.handleRequestClose}>
                // Content
            </Dialog>
        </div>
        );
    }
}
```

I'm a beginer with JS, so if my code isn't right somewhere I will appreciate some comments too.

Edit: This is my code now after the modification:

```
class AuthDialog extends React.Component {
    constructor(props, context){
        super(props, context);

        this.state = {
            // State of authBody
        };  
    };

    render() {
        const { onRequestClose, open } = this.props;

        return (
            <Dialog open={open} onRequestClose={onRequestClose}>
                // Body of the dialog
            </Dialog>
        );
    }
}
```

And in the parent:

```
closeAuthDialog = () => {
    this.setState({
        openAuthDialog: false,
    });
}

openAuthDialog = () => {
    this.setState({
        openAuthDialog: true,
    });
}

<RaisedButton children="login" onTouchTap={ this.openAuthDialog } />
<AuthDialog open={this.state.openAuthDialog} onRequestClose={this.closeAuthDialog} handleLoginSuccess={ this.handleLoginSuccess } />
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to achieve that, you need to use the `props` instead of the local state.

```
class AuthDialog extends React.PureComponent {
    static propTypes = {
      open: React.PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
      onClose: React.PropTypes.func.isRequired,
      onOpen: React.PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    };

    render() {
      const { onClose, onOpen, open } = this.props;

      return (
        <div>
            <RaisedButton children="login" onTouchTap={onOpen} />
            <Dialog open={open} onRequestClose={onClose}>
                // Content
            </Dialog>
        </div>
      );
    }
}
```

and then from the parent class you need to send the two function and the open prop.

```
<AuthDialog open={open} onOpen={this.toggleOpenToTrue} onClose={this.toggleOpenToFalse} />
```

Comment: Thanks, that's what i need. But finally i didn't used the propTypes and I just done what @Yuriy Yakym posted. Seems that propTypes is deprecated and I don't want to add too much libraries.

Comment: It's great that you used a Stateless component as @Yuriy Yakym proposed, but even then you should define the proptypes for that component. Getting the PropTypes object from `import React, { PropTypes } from 'react'` is deprecated, because there's a new common package called `prop-types` -> `import PropTypes from 'prop-types'`, you should definitely define the propTypes on your stateless component

Answer (score 2):

Just get attributes you pass from `this.props` like this:

```
...
render() {
    const { open, onRaisedButtonClick } = this.props;
    return (
        <div>
            <RaisedButton children="login" onTouchTap={ onRaisedButtonClick } />
            <Dialog open={open} onRequestClose={this.handleRequestClose}>
                // Content
            </Dialog>
        </div>
    );
}
...
```

Also, when you have stateless component with no lifecycle methods, you can use functional component; it's much simpler and readable:

```
const AuthDialog = ({ open, onRaisedButtonClick }) => (
    <RaisedButton children="login" onTouchTap={ onRaisedButtonClick } />
    <Dialog open={open} onRequestClose={this.handleRequestClose}>
        // Content
    </Dialog>
)
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what you're exactly looking for. But from what I have understood, you want to use your AuthDialog component like this;

```
<AuthDialog open={open} />
```

And when the `<RaisedButton/>` is clicked, you need to show the `<Dialog />` and also to change the **'open'** state/var on the parent as well.

In this case you're gonna wanna go for Flux or Redux to manage your app state. Since two-way binding in React is a bad practice that will be your best shot at achieving this.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I don't need to two-way binding (not to the moment). I just wanted to pass all the control to the outside and delete the button form the AuthDialog. I achieved this thanks to Crysfel and Yuriy posts.

Comment: That is great, arracso!